# Is there a performance penalty when composing spark UDFs (rather than having UDFs as one)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm wondering if there is a performance penalty by composing spark udf. In general, I prefer to compose small functions that do one thing …

Here is a trivial example, given a `DataFrame` df :

```
def inc = udf( (i: Double) => i + 1)
def double = udf( (i: Double) => i * 2)
df.withColumn("r", double(inc($"c")))
```

versus

```
def incAndDouble = udf( (i: Double) => (i + 1) * 2)
df.withColumn("r", incAndDouble($"c")
```

From what I've seen, performance are the same on this simple example.

Can you explain why ? How Spark works behind the scene ?

Is it always true ?

**[update]**

I may have a counterexample when a clever combination (not just a simple function composition) is possible, as in the following example

```
def filter = udf((s: Seq[String]) => s.startsWith("A"))
def size = udf((s: Seq[String]) => s.size)

val filterAndSize = udf((s: Seq[String]) => s.count(_.startsWith("A")))
```

So, I guess that filterAndSize is preferable because it will avoid some intermediary collections instantiation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** There could be some performance degradation or penalty but it's negligible.

> Can you explain why ?

That's quite funny to see your question with "explain" which is exactly the name of the method to use to see what happens under the covers of Spark SQL and how it executes queries :)

So, use `Dataset.explain` or even its more verbose version `Dataset.explain(extended = true)` to see all the optimizations (and possible performance degradations).

```
def inc = udf( (i: Double) => i + 1)
def double = udf( (i: Double) => i * 2)

val df = Seq(1,2,3).toDF("c")
val q = df.withColumn("r", double(inc($"c")))
```

With the two UDFs composed the plans look as follows.

```
scala> q.explain(extended = true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [c#3, UDF(UDF('c)) AS r#10]
+- AnalysisBarrier Project [value#1 AS c#3]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
c: int, r: double
Project [c#3, if (isnull(if (isnull(cast(c#3 as double))) null else UDF(cast(c#3 as double)))) null else UDF(if (isnull(cast(c#3 as double))) null else UDF(cast(c#3 as double))) AS r#10]
+- Project [value#1 AS c#3]
   +- LocalRelation [value#1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [c#3, r#10]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [c#3, r#10]
```

Let's see how the plans look like with one UDF that's a combination of the two UDFs.

```
def incAndDouble = udf( (i: Double) => (i + 1) * 2)
val q = df.withColumn("r", incAndDouble($"c"))
scala> q.explain(extended = true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [c#3, UDF('c) AS r#16]
+- AnalysisBarrier Project [value#1 AS c#3]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
c: int, r: double
Project [c#3, if (isnull(cast(c#3 as double))) null else UDF(cast(c#3 as double)) AS r#16]
+- Project [value#1 AS c#3]
   +- LocalRelation [value#1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [c#3, r#16]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [c#3, r#16]
```

In this particular case, the difference is none since the physical plan is the same across the queries, i.e. `LocalTableScan`.

It could be different with other data sources like files or JDBC, but my personal recommendation is to develop UDFs as small as possible as they are black-boxes for Spark optimizer.

---

> Is it always true ?

No, not at all as it heavily depends on what you do in your UDF (but that has more to do with whether to write a UDF in the first place or not).

In the case of the following UDF that is a predicate (i.e. returns a boolean):

```
def filter = udf((s: Seq[String]) => s.startsWith("A"))
```

Spark could optimize the use of UDF (if it was **not** a UDF but a simple `filter` operation) and push it down to a data source to load less data. That could have a huge impact on the performance.

Comment: Hello @jacek.Thanks for your answer and your great Spark book ! If you have some time, I have a bunch of others spark questions on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1437346+[apache-spark]

Comment: On this same vein: is it possible to compose filters (as method of a class or object, for example) in a way they are testable as simple Scala code? Sometimes filters can get a little complex...

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I think so, but I'd like to see some code to be sure that we're talking about the same thing.